# Tumblr photoset blocking HTML

Tags: html, layout, themes, tumblr

I'm having a terrible time trying to figure out what the proper HTML code is for adjusting the width of my layout's photoset area. I've looked through a handful of previous solutions given by stackoverflowers, but have gotten nowhere. There seems to be a specific sort of hangup in the code I'm using that I just can't find and it's driving me bonkers.

This is the theme I'm using: http://pastebin.com/qePrzu7d

I would very much like to readjust the photoset's width to 650px. I know this can be done because of others who have asked/received help from the members of this website, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how. I even messaged the creator of this theme and asked her for help, but she replied saying she was too short on time and that it was too complicated to tell me how. If anyone could give me a hand, I'd be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 500px photoset variable with the 700px photoset variable in your theme's html.

```
{block:Photoset}
<div class="image">{Photoset-700}</div>
{block:IfShowCaption}<div class="cap">
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
</div>{/block:IfShowCaption}

{block:IfNotShowCaption}{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:PermalinkPage}{/block:IfNotShowCaption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

700px is closer to 650px than 500px is, but you cannot resize photosets easily using css or javascript because they are iframes — if you don't really care about the layout of the photos within the photosets, you can replace the photoset variable with this instead:

```
{block:Photos}
{block:Photo1}{/block:Photo1}
<div class="photoset_image">
<img src="{PhotoWidth-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
<div class="photoset_caption">{Caption}</div>
</div>                            
{/block:Photos}
```

This will display all of the photos within the photoset individually, and you can style them however you want.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up using the second code you provided, and tweaked the .entry dimensions, and it worked perfectly! You have no idea how happy I am to have had this answered, thank you thank you thank you.